# How to validate mssql server credentials

Tags: inno-setup

In my project, I use Inno to run a .sql script to create a database. I use a custom page to write SQL Server instance name user and password to run the script.
I would like to add the validation of the entered credentials. What's the best way?

Update:
I'm testing this approach

```
function ConnDBAndExecSql(istanza,utente,password:string):Boolean;   
var
  ADOConnection: Variant;  

begin
  Result := False;

  try 
    // create the ADO connection object
    ADOConnection := CreateOleObject('ADODB.Connection');
    // build a connection string; for more information, search for ADO
    // connection string on the Internet 
    ADOConnection.ConnectionString := 
      'Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;' +               // provider
      'Data Source='+ istanza +';' + // server name
      'Persist Security Info=True;' +
      'User Id=' + utente + ';' + // user name
      'Password='+ password + '; '; // password
    // open the connection by the assigned ConnectionString 
    ADOConnection.Open;
    Result := True;
    //ADOConnection.Connected:=True;
  except
    Result:= False;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Run `sqlcmd` to test the credentials.

Comment: If you have a solution, please post it *as an answer*.

Comment: I will definitely do it but it is not a solution yet but for now it is just a road that I am testing since there is some error for sure